# Only return button state once in X amount of time?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, button

I want to detect if a button has been pressed, but what I don't want is for it to keep returning the "pressed" state more than once within a second or two.

For example, with this code:

```c
void loop() {
  passButtonState = digitalRead(passButton);

  if (passButtonState == LOW) {
    Serial.println("PASSED!");
  }
}
```

Would spit out something like this with a single quick press of the button:

```
PASSED!
PASSED!
PASSED!
PASSED!
PASSED!
PASSED!
PASSED!
PASSED!
PASSED!
```

But what I want is for a single button press to just return `PASSED!` once for that single button press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this problem you can use a boolean variable as a flag that permit to enter inside the `if` only once.

```
bool flag = true;

void loop() {
  passButtonState = digitalRead(passButton);

  if (passButtonState == LOW && flag) {
    Serial.println("PASSED!");
    flag = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: But this permanently disables that button from then on. I just want it to only return once for each press as opposed to a dozen.

Comment: @Shpigford you can reset the `flag = true` after a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, I think the answer might be a pretty common one. Your circuit may be suffering from "bounce" and the solution is called "debounce."

Check out this link for a possible solution:
[Software Debounce](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/SoftwareDebounce)

Answer (score 0):

```
void loop() {
  passButtonState = digitalRead(passButton);

  if (passButtonState == LOW) {
    Serial.println("PASSED!");
    while (passButtonState == LOW) delay(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a delay.

```
void loop() {
  passButtonState = digitalRead(passButton);

  if (passButtonState == LOW) {
    Serial.println("PASSED!");
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this would be a good solution? While it may be trivial to you and me, it certainly won't be to everyone. Also, you should state that adding a delay will "slow" the whole program. You might even give alternative solutions.